# Android app running on device access localhost server (on MacBook) in my case

Tags: android, macos, localhost, wildfly

I am using MacBook to develop Android application. I have also developed a Java EE app running on my localhost server. **Now, I want my Android app running on device communicate to my localhost server(wildfly) running on MacBook. I tried the following steps:**

- On my **MacBook** I did the following things:

  1. Establish the internet connection by connecting my MacBook with a wired Ethernet cable through an adapter.
  2. I go to System Preferences --> Sharing --> choose "Share my connection from Thunderbolt Ethernet" To "computers using Wi-Fi" --> enable "Internet Sharing"
  3. I checked the IP address of my MacBook now, it is `192.168.2.30`
- On my **Android device** I did the following things:

  1. Turn on Wi-Fi option, I see my MacBook hotspot, my Android device successfully connected to my MacBook hotspot.
  2. My Android application is programmed to access server at `http://192.168.2.30/MyServerApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest`
  3. I install my Android app and run it on device. But it is not able to access my localhost server. I am not able to access localhost from device browser either. My device IP is `192.168.1.2` **Why ? Where am I wrong or missing?**

P.S. in my Android app, I **have** all the required permissions e.g. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, my app is able to access the production server. My problem is on localhost server access.

Comment: Can you access your localhost server from the browser on the device. Also check your device IP in the wifi settings.

Comment: No, I am not able to access localhost from browser either. See my update please.

Comment: Check your server settings and see if it is listening on the correct ip. If it is port 80. From terminal run netstat -an | grep 80 and see on what ip is the server listening.

Comment: Did you remember to put this in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @ Mobility, my server is running on the right IP on port 8080

Answer (score 0):

In your description you do not mention making any changes to the IP address that WildFLy is bound to, by default it is localhost which means it is not accessible to any remote clients.

If you start WildFly with the following command: -

./standalone.sh -b 192.168.2.30

This will now cause WildFly to be listening on the public IP address of your computer.

Alternatively edit the standalone.xml and within the interfaces section change the public interface definition to: -

```
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="192.168.2.30"/>
    </interface>
```

Comment: Actually thay may not be relevent, reading your description again you say the app is coded to access one address and your computer is running with a different address, the Android app is going to have to use the address of your mac unless that alternative address is some form of proxy or firewall forwarding requests to your mac.